# Nested scss is not working when applied to the child component in angular

Tags: css, sass, angular-material, css-selectors, angular12

Parent HTML

```
 <childComponent class="applyToChild"> </childComponent>
```

In ChildComponent HTML

```
<p>ABCD</p>
<ul>
<li>
<p> XYZ </p>
<li>
</ul>
```

.scss of Parent (applying styles in the parent component) is not getting refeleted

```
 .applyToChild{
    
    p {
    font-size:25px;
    }
    
    ul
  {
      li{
        background-color:blue;
       }
   }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because your style is encapsulated. One way around this is to use the ::ng-deep pseudo-selector:

```
:host ::ng-deep {
    .applyToChild{
        p {
            font-size:25px;
        }
        ul {
            li{
                background-color:blue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```